# Band-stop notch filter question

Tags: filter, transfer-function

Which value of \$\omega_0\$ would you choose for the following transfer function to eliminate the 60 Hz component of a signal?

$$
  H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{[1-e^{-j(\omega - \omega_0)}][1-e^{-j(\omega + \omega_0)}]}
  {[1-0.9e^{-j(\omega - \omega_0)}][1-0.9e^{-j(\omega + \omega_0)}]}
$$

Comment: What do you think the answer is, and why?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not sure how to approach this. Can you give me a tip?

Comment: You have one variable to play with; how can you make \$H =0\$?

Comment: Do you need a notch filter for 60Hz or you wanna only solve this equation for 60Hz? practical or mathematical?

Comment: Clearly there is a zero at \$\omega_0 = \pm\omega\$ so that is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip of the day: -

If the formula *is* of a notch filter then whatever value of \$\omega\$ makes the numerator zero at 60Hz is the correct answer.

Comment: Clearly there is a zero at \$\omega_0 = \pm\omega\$ so that is the answer

Answer (score 1):

As you want to eliminate f=60Hz,

$$\mid H(e^{jw})\mid = 0 $$ for $$w=2\pi * 60 rad$$

$$\frac{\mid (1-e^{-j(w-w_{0})})(1-e^{-j(w+w_{0})})\mid}{\mid (1-0.9e^{-j(w-w_{0})})(1-0.9e^{-j(w+w_{0})})\mid}=0$$

$$\mid (1-e^{-j(w-w_{0})})(1-e^{-j(w+w_{0})})\mid=0$$

$${\mid1- e^{-j(w-w_{0})}-e^{-j(w+w_{0})}+e^{-j2w}\mid}=0$$

$${\mid1- e^{-jw}(e^{jw_{0}}+e^{-jw_{0}})+e^{-j2w}\mid}=0$$

$${\mid1- 2e^{-jw}cos(w_{0})+e^{-j2w}\mid}=0$$

now $$w=2\pi*60, e^{-jw}=1$$

Thus,
$$\mid2-2cos(w_{0}) \mid=0$$

$$cos(w_{0})=1$$

Determine w0 for yourself

Comment: This looks more complex than necessary. There is a zero at \$\omega_0 = \pm \omega\$ so that is the answer. Also, the transfer function is discrete time and the signal with the 60Hz component from the original continuous time signal. I omitted those details. Thank you so much for the help on this.